# Solve integration using Laplace Transform Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method

Show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (t)}{t}dt=\frac{\pi }{2}$$ by using Laplace Transform method.
I know that $$L\left \{\sin(t) \right \} = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin(t)dt=\frac{1}{s^{2}+1}$$ how to proceed further ?

Comment: Use the derivative/integral property of Laplace Transform

Comment: Did you finish this problem @shoyab khan?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\mathcal L (\sin t/t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} e^{-st} \ dt = \arctan\frac{1}{s}.$$

**EDIT:**
To arrive at this result, note that
\begin{align*}
I & = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} e^{-st} \ dt \\
-\frac{\partial I}{\partial s} & = \int_0^\infty \sin t e^{-st} \ dt\\
& = \frac{1}{1+s^2}.
\end{align*}
Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thanx but i want to know how to solve this integration.

Comment: Your OP suggested you wanted to know how to go from the transform to showing that it the above integral equals $\pi/2$.

Comment: I would have to agree with OP that this answer is probably a little lacking for their needs. Nothing wrong with looking stuff up in a table, everyone does it all the time. But sometimes doing the derivation is the important part.

Comment: I will update the post.

Comment: Yes now it is clear. Thanx @Gregory

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (t)}{t}dt$

$=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-0\cdot t}\frac{\sin t}{t} dt$

$=\lim_{s\to 0}\int_s^{\infty}L[\sin t] ds$

$=\lim_{s\to 0}\int_s^{\infty}\frac{1}{s^2+1} ds$

$=\lim_{s\to 0}\left.\tan^{-1}(s)\right|_s^\infty$

$=\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}(s)$

$=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$ \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)dx = \int_0^\infty (Lf)(s)(L^{-1}g)(s)ds $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (t)}{t}dt&=&\int_0^\infty \sin t \cdot\frac1tdt=\int_0^\infty L\{\sin t\}L^{-1}\{\frac1t\}ds\\
&=&\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s^2+1}\cdot 1ds=\frac{\pi }{2}
\end{eqnarray}